# How to access id in modal dialog with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I am trying to push all contents of html to jsp with jQuery.

I made an empty div like this :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="formModal_title"></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" id="viewDiv">
                <div class="widget-body padding-10" id="modal_container" style="height: 430px; overflow: auto;">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I made a HTML with jQuery.get() from other html. like...

```
    $.get('/resources/news.html', function(data){
        $('#modal_container').append($(data).fadeIn());
    });

    //main_exposure is not important here.
    $('#main_exposure').find('tr').each(function(){
        var nid = $(this).attr('nid');
        var news_cd = $(this).attr('news_cd');
        for(var idx in setting_news_cds){
            if(setting_news_cds[idx] == news_cd){
                console.log(generateHTML($('#' + news_cd).html('')));
            }               
        }
    });
```

then my console.log() prints undefined, even though I can see id and data from chrome Inspector.

After times of trying, I found I can not find any of result of $.get() in 'view page source'(right click and 'view page source' in browser).

Is there any way to access id in modal witch made in dynamic way(This means $.get())?

Comment: If the JS part with main_exposure is not relevant for this question, please remove it.

Comment: `get` is asynchronous. Move the `$('#main_exposure').find` code inside it or put in it its own function and call it from `get`.

Comment: @Andy Thanks Andy. So I changed this get() to ajax(). according to docs, it is same with ajax. All I need to do was add asynchronous option in $.ajax. like `async : false`. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing with new HTML not showing up in page source is not related to the get() function, but in DOM changes through JS in general. The page source view only shows what came with the initial response from server. You will see all changes in any inspector and Firebug though.

The problem you're having with finding the right elements that were added to the DOM probably comes from the fact that you're adding the contents asynchronously and you're trying to access the elements before they're loaded. Or in other words: You tell jQuery to get() contents and you search for these contents before the get is fully done. Put the code you want to be executed on newly loaded content inside the callback function you're using to append the HTML - the function you pass to get().

Your code might look something like this after the change:

```
$.get('/resources/news.html', function(data){
    $('#modal_container').append($(data).fadeIn());

    //main_exposure is not important here.
    $('#main_exposure').find('tr').each(function(){
        var nid = $(this).attr('nid');
        var news_cd = $(this).attr('news_cd');
        for(var idx in setting_news_cds){
            if(setting_news_cds[idx] == news_cd){
                console.log(generateHTML($('#' + news_cd).html('')));
            }               
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not use your solution, since I watch this too late. however, you exactly aware what was wrong in my code. Thanks for sharing your solution. have a good day!